# seamless WCF webservices over Websphere MQ 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis, ibm-mq

I'm trying to create a WCF webservice using WMQ transport. Hosted on IIS.

I couldn't find  good documentation on the subject.  And from the examples I did find it appears there's much detail that needs to be programmed "manaualy" (when comparing to WCF web services using MSMQ transport)

Comment: Do you already know how to connect MSMQ to Websphere MQ?

Comment: What do you mean?  To define a MSMQ based service, and bridge to WMQ? This appears to an overkill

Comment: I'm trying to make sure you have basic connectivity to MQ before working on **WCF** connectivity to MQ.

Comment: Connectivity to MQ works fine.  So does the samples that come with WMQ.  But they are very code intensive. I assume at least part of the code can be replaced by configuration files or autogenerated.  Additionally, they cover only self hosting and not IIS.

Answer (score 3):

WMQ configuration for WCF is quite easy - I tried it few months ago an it is only about providing bindingElement extension in configuration file, using the extension in custom binding and specifying endpoint with that binding and rather complex JMS URI specific for WCF. Thats all.

But IBM doesn't provide any support for hosting in IIS. The support is only for self-hosting. If you want IIS hosting you need to build your own external WAS listener and integration with IIS (you need to do IBM's job) - [here is extensibility sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717041%28v=vs.100%29) related to building WAS listener.

Side note: Tibco EMS (competitive technology) provides WAS listener.